# Trying to hide a Nav bar on specific a viewing point in the site using FullpageJS

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

Below im trying to use the Js script to remove the fp-slidesNav.bottom bar in a specific viewing site (in this case page 5). It dosent seems to work quite as i want to. I've scratching my brains and pulling my hair for hours now and dont really know whats wrong. also i have tried to change from #fp-nav -> .fp-slidesNav.bottom. Also to add i have tried to do it using the css:

```
 body.fp-viewing-5-0 #fp-nav {
 display:none;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#wrapper').fullpage( { 

 anchors: ['.fp-viewing-5-0'],
 afterRender: function(){
 $('#fp-nav').hide();
 },

 afterLoad: function(anchor, index){
 if(index == 1){
   $('#fp-nav').fadeOut();
  }
   else{
    $('#fp-nav').fadeIn();
   }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the afterLoad callback, otherwise you'll be using fadeIn in all sections that are not the 1st one, and it seems you want to hide it on the 5th.

Remove this:

```
afterLoad: function(anchor, index){
 if(index == 1){
   $('#fp-nav').fadeOut();
  }
   else{
    $('#fp-nav').fadeIn();
   }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this link https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-origin-destination-direction

example code:

```
onLeave: function (origin, destination, direction) {
    $('header #mobile-nav').collapse('hide');

    var loadedSection = this;

    if (origin == 2) {
        $('#fp-nav').hide();
    }

},
afterLoad: function (origin, destination, direction) {
    var loadedSection = this;

    if (destination == 2) {
        $('#fp-nav').hide();
    }
}
```